# Running my code in terminal doesn't work because in cannot find one of the files

Tags: python, terminal, file-not-found

I have created a project (test) in Pycharm where I have three files; one file with my code/function (test1), one which calls and executes the function (krypt.py), and a txt file that the functions gathers information from (data.txt). When I try to run the code in Terminal I get this error:

```
(base) KKWs-MBP-2:~ Kristoffer$ /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/test/krypt.py"
Nøkkel: 
Vil du lese eller legge til? (r/a) r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/test/krypt.py", line 2, in <module>
    Hent()
  File "/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/test/test1.py", line 27, in Hent
    with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.txt'
```

What do I have to give Terminal for it to be able to read the txt-file?

Comment: Is the .txt file in the same folder as the script? Also why are you opening a text file with `rb` option? This is for binary files. Use `r` for plain text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.txt` is not in the directory that you are executing this script from.

From your PS1 it looks like you are in your home directory, which is where the program is looking for `data.txt`.

Try navigating to the directory with the `data.txt` file and then running the same command. Or making the path absolute in the program that you have written.